# object in object for Json built by JsonBuilder() in Groovy

Tags: json, groovy, properties, jsonbuilder

My Groovy is 2.4.0

My code:

```
def builder2 = new JsonBuilder()
builder2.book {
    isbn '0321774094'
    title 'Scala for the Impatient'
    author (['Cay S. Horstmann', 'Hellen'])
    publisher 'Addison-Wesley Professional'
    content99 {
        contentType '1'
        text 'Hello'
    }
}
println(builder2.toPrettyString())
println(builder2.content)
println(builder2.content99)
println(builder2.book)
```

The results are as below:

```
{
    "book": {
        "isbn": "0321774094",
        "title": "Scala for the Impatient",
        "author": [
            "Cay S. Horstmann",
            "Hellen"
        ],
        "publisher": "Addison-Wesley Professional",
        "content99": {
            "contentType": "1",
            "text": "Hello"
        }
    }
}

[book:[isbn:0321774094, title:Scala for the Impatient, author:[Cay S. Horstmann, Hellen], publisher:Addison-Wesley Professional, content99:TestJson$_testJson_closure1$_closure2@38ee79e5]]

Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: content99 for class: groovy.json.JsonBuilder

Groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: book for class: groovy.json.JsonBuilder
```

My questions are:

1. When I println builder2.content, why the content of content99 does not display (it only displays the class something)?
2. When I println builder2.content99, Groovy tells me that:

   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: content99 for class: groovy.json.JsonBuilder
3. Even I tried to println builder2.book, Groovy still tells me the same error:

   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: book for class: groovy.json.JsonBuilder

How do I read the property in the Json object ?

Thank you.

Comment: `isbn '...'` implies `isbn('...')` and not `isbn = '...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because of this [method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html#getContent()). Since `getContent()` is defined for `JsonBuilder`, `content` can be called. There's no `getContent99()` method, nor property. You mismatch `JsonSlurper` with `JsonBuilder`. With `JsonBuilder` it's not possible to refer to a field in such a way.
2. See 1.
3. In order to refer to fields you need to parse the built document again:

   ```
   import groovy.json.*

   def builder2 = new JsonBuilder()
   builder2.book {
       isbn '0321774094'
       title 'Scala for the Impatient'
       author (['Cay S. Horstmann', 'Hellen'])
       publisher 'Addison-Wesley Professional'
       content99 {
           contentType '1'
           text 'Hello'
       }
   }

   def pretty = builder2.toPrettyString()
   println(pretty)
   println(builder2.content)
   def slurped = new JsonSlurper().parseText(pretty)

   println(slurped.book.content99)
   println(slurped.book)
   ```

Comment: This failed for me with multiple errors such as `wound up catching org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2.call;` and `java.io.NotSerializableException: groovy.json.internal.LazyMap`